# Update the src of image using ajax response

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am trying to update the profile picture of user via ajax. So far I have stored the new image in db, displayed the loading gif, but I am unable to update the image which is being displayed. I am having problem attaching the response variable to src attribute which is again generated using laravel url().

```
success: function(data){
  $('#displayPhoto').html('<img src="{{url('images/profile/')}}.data[0]" alt="" class="responsive-img" style="height: 132px; width: 132px;">');
 });
```

Comment: $(selector).attr('src', YourImagePath);

Comment: @Yojan, the comment above is the best answer you've got, assuming you have a placeholder image when one isn't set.

Comment: @rush-2707, please add this as an actual answer :o)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You [shouldn't mix PHP and JS](https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices#do-not-put-js-and-css-in-blade-templates-and-do-not-put-any-html-in-php-classes). A better way to use URL in a controller method and return full URL to JS, for example:

```
$('#displayPhoto').html('<img src="' + data[0] + '" alt="" class="responsive-img" style="height: 132px; width: 132px;">');
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I feel like an idiot having not thought about it.

Comment: That's not PHP. That's Blade engine syntax which will be translated into PHP and doesn't make any problem inside that JS.

Comment: @revo Laravel converts this to pure PHP at runtime. That's how Laravel Blade works. From the docs "all Blade views are compiled into plain PHP code and cached until they are modified".

Comment: I said the same already. That doesn't make any problem. I should say *it's not the problem.*

Comment: It's not PHP! and no, because you thought the wrong way and it doesn't provide a fully functional answer to question.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin PLUS 1. Sometimes we have to adjust because some people can't understand :)

Comment: I'm not here to defend your understandings. If you think a different syntax is PHP yet that's a fail in your understanding not me. @AniketSahrawat

Comment: I'm repeating my old comments: It's not PHP and it doesn't provide a fully functional answer to the question, frankly and obviously.

Comment: I'm always arguing this part of SO that revenge down-vote should be intelligently avoided. A gold-badge holder in Laravel / PHP fails in distinguishing things from each other. *Gosh!*

Comment: Why do you keep repeating your argument? There is a problem with the code, and this answer makes an intelligent suggestion as to how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

In js if you want to append data, you must use the '+' instead of the diacritic '.'
Edit code :

```
success: function(data){
  $('#displayPhoto').html('<img src="'+data[0]+'" alt="" class="responsive-img" style="height: 132px; width: 132px;">');
 });
```